# LetsEncrypt Certbot-Auto freezes when trying to run any command on Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am trying to get LetsEncrypt SSL certificates installed on a Centos 6 server using Cerbot-Auto, however no matter what I try, it just hangs on:

```
Apache version is 2.2.15
```

**Command**

```
./certbot-auto -v
```

When I press **CTRL + C** to exit the program, it takes about 15 seconds and then exits with a stack trace:

```
Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('letsencrypt==0.7.0', 'console_scripts', 'letsencrypt')()
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1240, in main
    return config.func(config, plugins)
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 981, in run
    installer, authenticator = plug_sel.choose_configurator_plugins(config, plugins, "run")
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot/plugins/selection.py", line 189, in choose_configurator_plugins
    authenticator = installer = pick_configurator(config, req_inst, plugins)
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot/plugins/selection.py", line 25, in pick_configurator
    (interfaces.IAuthenticator, interfaces.IInstaller))
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot/plugins/selection.py", line 77, in pick_plugin
    verified.prepare()
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 248, in prepare
    return [plugin_ep.prepare() for plugin_ep in six.itervalues(self._plugins)]
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 248, in <listcomp>
    return [plugin_ep.prepare() for plugin_ep in six.itervalues(self._plugins)]
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 130, in prepare
    self._initialized.prepare()
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 225, in prepare
    self.parser = self.get_parser()
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot_apache/override_centos.py", line 39, in get_parser
    self.version, configurator=self)
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot_apache/override_centos.py", line 47, in __init__
    super(CentOSParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot_apache/parser.py", line 74, in __init__
    if self.find_dir("Define", exclude=False):
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/certbot_apache/parser.py", line 401, in find_dir
    "%s//*[self::directive=~regexp('%s')]" % (start, regex))
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/augeas.py", line 413, in match
    ctypes.byref(array))
KeyboardInterrupt
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.
```

I thought it may be a python version issue but when checked, the server is running Python 2.6.6, which, according to the [Certbot System Requirements](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/intro.html#system-requirements) is acceptable.

**Letsencrypt.log**

When I checked the log, it is exactly the same stacktrace as was reported by the script previously.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am still trying to solve this problem, my latest discovery is that if you leave the command running overnight, it will work as expected after 7 hours... I believe it may be a network configuration issue, namely something to do with IPV6.